# openvpn conecta desde local pero no desde ip publica

Tags: vpn, port

acabo de crear una vpn en un servidor, el mismo si estoy dentro de la misma red puedo conectarme mediante un cliente pero al querer cambiar la ip del archivo ovpn del servidor local a la ip publica el mismo ya no me conecta.
tengo en mi modem abierta la puerta 1194/udp y en mi firewall tambien, cuando le tiro un nmap el mismo me dice open/filtering y no se si sea esto lo que esta ocasionando que no pueda acceder.
Cualquier orientacion es agradecida desde ya!

Comment: ya creastes la redireccion de los puertos en router/firewall? tu ip publica es propia o parte de `CGNAT`?

Comment: La IP es pública estatica propia, los puertos ya los abri en ambos lados, estoy pensando si será un tema interno de la compañía de teléfono que no me habilite la transferencia por puertos udp para no realizar vpn. Porque como sigo, llegar llego pero el mismo no me responde.